# Vim ripgrep searching for pipe symbol

Tags: vim, ripgrep

Trying to search in vim using ripgrep `:Rg` for e.g. '||'.

Have tried:

```
:Rg --hidden --no-ignore '||'
:Rg --hidden --no-ignore '\|\|'
:Rg --hidden --no-ignore "||"
:Rg --hidden --no-ignore "\|\|"
```

But it just matches every column of every line.

According to the manual you can use `--fixed-strings`, but when I do

```
:Rg --fixed-strings --hidden --no-ignore '||'
:Rg --fixed-stringsssssssssssssssssss --hidden --no-ignore '||'
```

It still ignores any number of 's' to complain

```
 1 || error: Found argument '--fixed-string' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
 2 ||  Did you mean --fixed-strings?
 3 ||
 4 || USAGE:
 5 ||
 6 ||     rg [OPTIONS] PATTERN [PATH ...]
 7 ||     rg [OPTIONS] [-e PATTERN ...] [-f PATTERNFILE ...] [PATH ...]
 8 ||     rg [OPTIONS] --files [PATH ...]
 9 ||     rg [OPTIONS] --type-list
10 ||     command | rg [OPTIONS] PATTERN
11 ||
12 || For more information try --help
13 ||
```

How do I use [Vim Ripgrep](https://github.com/jremmen/vim-ripgrep) to search for `||`?

Comment: Doing `rg '\|\|'` in the console works as expected. Just when Vim is trying to ripgrep there is problem ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)

Comment: Maybe this is because of (insane) Vim escaping rules, which add to the escaping required by `rg` (the external program) itself? The command is defined [like so](https://github.com/jremmen/vim-ripgrep/blob/ec87af6/plugin/vim-ripgrep.vim#L148): `command! -nargs=* -complete=file Rg :call s:Rg(<q-args>)`, I’d suggest you check Vim’s manual for the escaping rules induced by that. Sorry… The `--fixed-strings` issue, on the other hand, looks like a bug in the plugin; try to report it perhaps?

Comment: Maybe try: `\\|\\|`

Comment: Aha that worked! I'd tried `\\\|\\\|` but not `\\|\\|`
 ⊂(´・◡・⊂ )∘˚˳° Put as answer